# Java String delete tokens contains numbers

Tags: java, string, token, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have a string like this and I would like to eliminate all the tokens that contain a number:

```
 String[] s="In the 1980s".split(" ");
```

Is there a way to remove the tokens that contain numbers - in this case `1980s`, but also, for example `784th` or `s787`?

Comment: 1980 is a number but not 1980s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `\w*\d\w*` regex matcher for that. It will match all words with at least one digit in them. Although I generally despise regexes, they are particularily well suited for your problem.

```
String[] s = input.replaceAll("\\w*\\d\\w* *", "").split(" +");
```

See [Java lib docs for Pattern/Matcher (RegEx)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more reference how to work with regexes in general.

Test code:
http://ideone.com/LrHDsT

Comment: This solution generates additional empty string at start of result array if first word will contain digit.

Comment: @Pshemo although the example was given just for the same of reference, thanks for spotting that, IFTFY.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unwanted words first, then split:

```
String[] s = str.replaceAll("\\w*\\d\\w*", "").trim().split(" +");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "666 In the 1980s 784th s787 foo BAR";
String[] s = str.replaceAll("\\w*\\d\\w*", "").trim().split(" +");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Output:

```
[In, the, foo, BAR]
```

Comment: as Pshemo noted, this regex kind of fails if the first word contains numbers, because it produces an empty string there due to `.split()`

Comment: @vaxquis well it succeeds now - just added `trim()` before `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could Regex as suggested by @vaxquis or alternately after splitting the string based on the delimiter

You could Parse the token strings and check if the token has number among them using [NumberUtils.isNumber](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29) and remove those tokens.

Answer (score 0):

`split` doesn't seem to be what you are looking for. Even if you remove words which contain digit like in case of

```
"1foo f2oo bar whatever baz2"
```

you will end up with

```
"  bar whatever "
```

and if you split on spaces now you will end up with `["", "bar", "whatever"]`.

To solve this problem you may want also to remove spaces after word you removed so now

```
"1foo f2oo bar whatever baz2"
```

would become

```
"bar whatever "
```

so it can be split correctly (space at the end is not the problem since `split` by default removes trailing empty strings in result array).

---

But instead of doing two iterations (removing words and splitting on string) you can achieve same thing with only one iteration. All you need to do is use opposite approach:instead of focusing on removing wrong elements, lets try to find correct ones.
Correct tokens seem to be words which contains any non-space characters but not digits. You can regex representing such words with this regex `\b[\S&&\D]\b` where:

- `\b` represents word boundaries,
- `\S` any non whitespace character
- `\D` any non digit character
- `[\S&&\D]` intersection of non-whitespaces and non-digits, in other words non whitespaces which are also non-ditigts

Demo:

```
String input = "1foo f2oo bar whatever baz2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[\\S&&\\D]+\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
bar
whatever
```

---

BTW to avoid potential problems with potential empty element at start of results you can use `Scanner` which doesn't return empty element if delimiter is found at start of string. So we can simply set delimiter as series of spaces or words which contains digit. So your code can also look like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
sc.useDelimiter("(\\s|\\w*\\d\\w*)+");
while (sc.hasNext())
    System.out.println(sc.next());
sc.close();
```

Comment: it fails on any word sequence beginning with a "numeric" word, e.g. `1980s music wasn't bad.`; you'd have to do additional matching here, making the regexp even more convoluted.

Comment: @vaxquis You are right. Didn't thought about this case. It could be solved by adding `(^\\d\\w*)?` before current regex. For now I will delete this answer, but will try to add simpler solution.

Comment: Hm. AFAIK, the solution is to remove the extraneous spaces too with the word. As such, you're actually shooting pigeons with an ICBM here. Still, I admire your regex bravery.

Comment: @vaxquis I am not sure what you mean. This solution doesn't return spaces. Also it doesn't require traversing through string twice (once for replacing once for splitting) so this weapon feels lighter than ICMB :)

Comment: `Even if you remove words which contain digit ` etc. - you can remove the word *and* the spaces at once, making the splitting trivial; also, OP asked for solution to *eliminate* the unneeded tokens - the `split` is there just because he used it in the example.

Comment: @vaxquis OK, I updated my answer a little. But "the `split` is there just because he used it in the example" for me it looks like `split` was used there to let OP later iterate over all tokens. With approaches from my answer it can be done at same time so explicit split is not needed. But like I said my code is based on idea to find valid words while yours is to find (and remove) invalid ones. Anyway thanks for your input :)